# jquerymobile: how to dispay both left, right icons for a button

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can I display both left, right `data-icon`s for a button in jquerymobile.
Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
nehatha

Answer (score 1):

In jQuerymobile documentation, you can fix icon position to one area. If you want to display both (left and right), customized CSS and JS are needed.

```
data-iconpos="left"

data-iconpos="right"

data-iconpos="top"

data-iconpos="bottom"
```

Comment: Hi @ppshein, can I use two `data-iconpos`for same button. can you provide more details about custom css and js needed. Thank you.

Comment: You can use only data-iconpos in one button.

Comment: Hi ppshein, I have used `<a href="#" class="btn" onclick="javascript: loadpage();" data-theme="b" data-role="button" data-iconpos="left" data-iconpos="right" ><span id="title">Page2</span></a>` but it is not reflecting, i'm seeing only left icon.

Comment: Nope.. I mean, you can use **ONLY ONE** data-iconpos attribute in one button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your header part:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
    <h1>Add Contacts</h1>
    <a href="" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="fade">Search</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a grid inside your button, then add an image in the left column then css style it to look the same

```
<a data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-theme="b" href="#" 
        data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <img src="image.png" class="iconleft"/>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            Button
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-c">
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.iconleft {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -9px;
    left: -5px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    background-color: #666;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    background-image: url(images/icons-18-white.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    border-radius: 9px;
}
```

You can always do it the other way around, with the left being the dataicon and right being image but it doesn't really matter.

See my working example [here](http://fromthesidelines.net/stats/mobile) or [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsAZh/)